# Getting JSON from WEB API to R - Beginner here

Tags: r, json, httr, webapi, jsonlite

Im trying to get JSON from webapi to R

From the following website
http://wbes.srldc.in/Report/GetCurrentDayFullScheduleMaxRev?regionid=4&ScheduleDate=31-05-2020

When i try in browser, getting a proper response.

However when i try in R using any method, the fetched data is of a different html page without any JSON format.

Im just starting with R without any programming background. Please help

Comment: This is the error im getting. Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html>  <html lang="en
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Thanks for including the error, please [edit] your question and place that error text *plus the code you used that returned the error* (in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), please). We can typically help better when we have something clear to start from. Thanks!

Comment: Further: that web page appears to ask for a login, so I don't know that many people are going to be able to assist without clear mid-steps on your part. This will help significantly if you can walk through what you've tried and what you're seeing. My guess is that if you are not yet, you will need to use `rvest` in order to do session management. (Perhaps realize that logging into a browser and then transferring a URL to the R console typically does not bring your authentication with the URL. Apologies if this is known, but it's not always intuitive.)

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain, it seems the website you're trying to access checks for user-agents to avoid scraping. I'd set a common user agent in `httr` (Chrome or Firefox are fine) and perform a single `GET` request. This should get you through scraping the `MaxRevision` value:

```r
library(httr)

url <- "http://wbes.srldc.in/Report/GetCurrentDayFullScheduleMaxRev?regionid=4&ScheduleDate=31-05-2020"
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"

res <- GET(url, user_agent(ua))
content(res)
#> $MaxRevision
#> [1] 216
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>